# Django Retrieving Picture ID

Tags: django

I'm trying to achieve the results of when a user clicks on a picture from the whiteboard, it will send an argument of the picture id to my function.

This is an example .This display all my users board and when he clicks on the board it will redirect the user with the board id to my function

```
<h4>My WHiteBoards</h4>
{% if board %} 
<ul>  
    {% for b in board %}         
    <li><a href ="{% url world:Boat b.id %}">{{ b.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

I'm trying to achieve  the same thing but with an image. When a users click on an image . I want to redirect the user with the argument of the image id to my function. I will know if it happens because my function will redirect the users to my profile but the problem is when the user clicks on the picture , it does not redirect. I think the reason is the hyperlink and the image ain't relating with to each other.

How can I fix this error so when a user clicks on a picture , he will be redirected with the argument of the picture ID

```
<li><a href ="{% url world:Like pet.id %}"><img src= "{{ pet.image.url }}">
```

My views.py

```
def Boat(request ,animal_id):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:LoginRequest'))

    picture = Picture.objects.filter(whiteboard=animal_id)
    return render(request,'boat.html',{'picture':picture})
```

URLconf.py

```
    ),
    url(
        r'^(?P<picture_id>\d+)/$',
        'pet.views.Like',
        name = 'Like'
    ),
```

My views.py

```
def Like(request,picture_id):
    everyone = Person.objects.all()
    return render(request,'everyone.html',{'everyone':everyone,'follow':True,})
```

I hope this make sense otherwise i'll try to rewrite it until it make sense.thank you :]

Comment: Where do you close the `<a>` and `<li>` tags in your code?

Comment: I think is how you close it <li><a href ="{% url world:Like pet.id %}"><img src= "{{ pet.image.url }}"></li></a>

Comment: Add closing tags to `<ul>`, `<li>` and `<a>` tags in **boat.html**. Edit your question and make it clear.

Comment: @arulmr I closed the tags

Comment: Have you tried it in your original code?

Comment: How can I fix this  so It could relate with each other   <li><a href ="{% url world:Like pet.id %}"><img src= "{{ pet.image.url }}"></li></a>

Comment: Is this correct `{% for pet in picture %}` ? You may have to do something like `{% for pet in picture.pet.all %}` depending upon you model and relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `</li>` and `</a>` is in the incorrect position, it must be:

```
<li>
   <a href ="{% url world:Like pet.id %}">
       <img src= "{{ pet.image.url }}" style="cursor:pointer">
   </a>
</li>
```

I added `cursor:pointer` in your image

**Update:**

OK I trace your codes, the problem why your picture do nothing because the `like and boat has the same url address`. Why it happen to be the same? even though they have different url name. Notice the address url above in your browser, they both return `http://localhost:8000/1/`.

Like url is:

```
    url(
        r'^(?P<picture_id>\d+)/$',
        'pet.views.Like',
        name = 'Like'
    ),

    //which return http://localhost:8000/1/ --> 1 is just a sample id
```

Boat url is:

```
    url(
        r'^(?P<animal_id>\d+)/$',
        'pet.views.Like',
        name = 'Like'
    ),

    //which return also http://localhost:8000/1/ --> 1 is just a sample id
```

To make it effective and fix, you must change the url address either one of them like this:

```
    url(
        r'^like/(?P<picture_id>\d+)/$',
        'pet.views.Like',
        name = 'Like'
    ),

    //which return now as http://localhost:8000/like/1/
```

Comment: Okay , if your not busy could you come fb

Comment: I get this error when I try to redirect the users to the same board .'url_name' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found . url_name is not yet define?

Comment: url_name must be `BoardCreator`. url_name it's just a sample, don't copy it

Comment: HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:BoardCreator')) . It's redirect the users to create another board . I just want to redirect the user to the same board. I'm sorry that i'm disturbing you.

Comment: return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:Boat', 
                kwargs={'animal_id': the_id(don't copy, change to valid id) }))

Comment: Okay , I think I understand half. We are going to reverse into the same board. How do we get the current id?arg , i don't think i even know what i'm talking about.

Comment: your Like model has a picture field so you can get the board id through that pciture field. Just connect it.

Comment: I got it . I worked in reverse to get the board name not the id . picture = Picture.objects.get(pk=1)
board = Board.objects.get(picture=picture)
print board 
<jim>

Comment: I got the id. and I put it reverse('world:Boat', kwargs={'animal_id'} ?

Comment: `kwargs={'animal_id': put_id_here}`. You need to research on your own if it is small thing

Comment: I'm sorry , when you click on comments . It return back to the previous page with the comments

Comment: maybe the id of the comments can pass. Your reverse is complicated

Comment: Okay . hmm Do you mean it's a long procedure to reverse back to the previous page with the comments?

Comment: yeah... maybe think in other way that will make you work simpler so that it will be easy to find solution. Maybe you will create another page like that....

Comment: cathy , thank you very much for helping me today .I'm going to delete the question and try to remake it later so people can understand it. goodnight super cathy :D

Comment: I though about creating another page before but I got to go sleep seem it's 3:01 am